# How can I block pip and python user packages

Tags: python, pip

I'm trying to prevent users from using pip to install packages in their home directories.

The output from `python3 -m site --help` would indicate that it is possible for a super user to disable the user site directory. But how is this done? I've tried setting `site.ENABLE_USER_SITE` from a `sitecustomize.py` but that doesn't help. Setting `PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1` in the environment or passing `-s` to python works but is not exactly a superuser tweak.

I've also tried to approach this by somehow disabling pip for users. We'd be quite happy for packages to be installed into venv environments but not user home directories. Is there anything I can put in `pip.conf` to forcibly disable `--user` installs.

Answer (score 2):

**Q:** Is there anything I can put in pip.conf to forcibly disable --user installs.

**A:** No. The config file can always be overridden according the the precedence defined in the [pip docs](https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/user_guide/#config-precedence):

> Command line options have precedence over environment variables, which have precedence over the config file.

**Q:** It is possible for a super user to disable the user site directory. But how is this done? Setting `PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1` in the environment or passing `-s` to python works but is not exactly a superuser tweak.

**A:** I came to this question through Google because I was finding the exact opposite - I do not see `PYTHONNOUSERSITE` actually changing the behaviour of pip:

```
$ docker run --net=host -it python:3.8 bash

$ pip install -U pip
Requirement already up-to-date: pip in /usr/local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (20.2.2)

$ ls -ltr ~/.local
ls: cannot access '/root/.local': No such file or directory

$ PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1 pip install --user typing-extensions
Collecting typing-extensions
  Downloading typing_extensions-3.7.4.3-py3-none-any.whl (22 kB)
Installing collected packages: typing-extensions
Successfully installed typing-extensions-3.7.4.3

$ ls -ltr ~/.local
total 4
drwxr-xr-x 3 root root 4096 Aug 24 07:08 lib
```

The [docs for `PYTHONNOUSERSITE`](https://docs.python.org/3/using/cmdline.html#envvar-PYTHONNOUSERSITE) state that:

> If this is set, Python won’t add the user site-packages directory to sys.path.

So even though I was surprised by the behaviour, I suppose it is reasonable for pip to still install to `PYTHONUSERBASE` even if this variable is set (even though the resulting *installed* package won't be available on the Python path).

I found a [relevant issue on the pip issue tracker](https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/5702) and it looks like there is already a special case for venvs which have system site packages disabled (the default) not being allowed to do user installs (I didn't explicitly check this).

So following through to the solution to that original bug report we arrive at a pull request which has some [interesting features](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/7155/files#diff-76f786bc1aed91c0c8e850af5d4f704eR90). Namely, there is apparently a special file that a super-user can create, ````, which disables the user site-package installation. I also found a [question on SO relating to this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3874179/741316). So I tried this, but unfortunately it still continued to install into the user base:

```
$ touch /usr/local/lib/python3.8/no-global-site-packages.txt

$ pip install --user typing-extensions
...
Successfully installed typing-extensions-3.7.4.3
```

Of course, this makes sense when we read the actual [pull request implementation](https://github.com/pypa/pip/pull/7155/files#diff-76f786bc1aed91c0c8e850af5d4f704eR104) which only checks for this file under virtualenv situations. In my case, I want to be able to *always* disable this behaviour, so I'll dig a little deeper into the pip codebase...

It turns out that the key function is [`decide_user_site`](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/20.2.2/src/pip/_internal/commands/install.py#L628), which [*does* honour the `site.ENABLE_USER_SITE`](https://github.com/pypa/pip/blob/20.2.2/src/pip/_internal/commands/install.py#L673) value, but *only* after it has checked for the explicit `user` argument. As we can see in the function itself this is asymmetric with how virtual environments are handled, which will prevent global/user installs if a virtual environment has disabled them. I consider this to be a bug, and I've raised it in https://github.com/pypa/pip/issues/8794.

So the answer is: It isn't currently possible, as far as I can tell, to disable `--user` installs in a base (i.e. non-virtual) environment. When it *is* possible to do so (hopefully when the issue linked above is fixed) the `-s` and `PYTHONNOUSERSITE=1` environment variables can be used, but the "sys-admin" way of doing this that I think you are looking for is to modify [site.py directly, as explained in the site.py implementation](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.8/Lib/site.py#L82).

Answer (score 1):

Old thread but here's possible solution.. Force pip to have virtual environment and not install directly on users site.

```
export PIP_REQUIRE_VIRTUALENV=true
```

Here's relevant link:
https://docs.python-guide.org/dev/pip-virtualenv/